# A query with those fields, that are not required to get from huge fields within a table

Tags: mysql, sql

i want a query to display few fields from a table on webpage, but there are huge number of fields in that table, but i want such type of **query that except few fields and displaying all remaining fields' data** on web page. 
Like: i have a table with 50 fields,

+--------+--------+--------+----------+       +----------+
|   Col1   |   Col2   |   Col3   |   Col4   |  ----  |   Col50  |
|---------|---------|----------|-----------|          |-----------|
|           |            |                  |                    |  ----  |                   |
|           |            |                  |                    |  ----  |                   |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+       +----------+

but i want to display only 48 fields on that page. then any query that except those 2 fields name(Col49 and Col50) that are not required and show remaining data. So instead of writing: 
**SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,...Col48 FROM table;**
 any alternate way to writing like that 
**SELECT *-(Col49,Col50) FROM table;**

Comment: can you add more details it is not much clear

Comment: i'm asking that, instead of writing all 18 fields name in that query, have you any alternate way to write that only 2 fields name that are not required from 20 fields.

Comment: please check it and if its ok mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is using view you can create view with those 18 columns and retrieve data form it

example

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM calls;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date       | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  6 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  7 | 2016-06-23 |    NULL |
+----+------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE VIEW C_VIEW AS
    ->     SELECT id,date from calls;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> select * from C_VIEW;
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |
|  6 | 2016-06-23 |
|  7 | 2016-06-23 |
+----+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please check this and let me know

Comment: its pretty cool but, not acceptable for everywhere because i have to required different fields at different places, that time this view hasn't any sense.

Comment: little bit yes! :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mentioning `select * from ...` include the column names in the query.. `select col1, col2,...col18 from ..`

Comment: if i have 50 fields and i want to display only 48 fields, then i have to write all 48 fields name one by one? have you any alternate way?

Comment: worked but not everywhere, i have to create different views at different places according to fields' need.

Comment: Now that depends on the logic to restrict the number of views.. you should consider the mostly picked columns and create lesser number of views..

Answer (score 0):

This answer is according to you question. So add more details to your question to get more clear answer. 
You need to pass column names to get data for only those columns.
e.g.

table_name = dummy_tab

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4
--------------------------------
  1   | John  |  20   | abc@def
--------------------------------
  2   |  Doe  |  21   | def@xyz

 ...
```

You can do:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM dummy_tab;
```

This will give:

```
 col_1 | col_2 
---------------
   1   | John 
---------------
   2   |  Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a pain but you can reduce effort and error by interrogating information_schema and excluding the fields you don't want by name or by position for example.

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (
    `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dte` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalMonth` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalMonthDescLong` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalMonthDescShort` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `calQtr` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
use information_schema;
select concat('`',REPLACE(t.NAME,'/dates','.'), '`',replace(T.NAME,'sandbox/',''),c.NAME,'`',',') 
from INNODB_SYS_TABLES  t
join    INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS c on c.TABLE_ID = t.TABLE_ID
where t.NAME like ('sandbox%')
    and t.name like ('%dates')
    and pos not in(1,4)
```

Best run from command line with the output piped to a text file.